# What is better to use: keeping track of amount in database or counting

Tags: sql, count

I'm creating a forum (for fun) in php and I want too show the amount of posts and topics per forum. Is it better to add a column to my forums in the database showing the number of thread/topics and whenever someone creates/deletes a topic it will get updated OR counting the amount of topics/threads everytime the forum page is loaded? What is common practice in this case?

Comment: Define "better". But in most of cases storing precalculated amount will be easier to use and faster.

Comment: how many posts/topics do you anticipate? 1 post with 1 topic = calculate the count each time. overhead = 0. billions of posts in millions of topics? cache the count somewhere. Somewhere in between? benchmark and figure out where the cutover point.

Comment: sorry, i mean better as in more common. I'm geussing most premade forums (for example phpNuke) all use the same method of counting threads/posts.

Comment: I would hide the operation behind an API and *not* store the count unless there was a *proven* reason to do so: use `COUNT` initially (it works and avoids a number of complications). If there is then indeed the case that `COUNT` is somehow insufficient (which *I highly doubt*), the model can be updated (triggers, background worker, sp, etc) and the API can "silently use the new faster model" without change to the rest of the application. In any case, ***storing the count as fundamental property of the model is not a clean design*** and it introduces redundant information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting records is the only reliable way to do this; if you store counts then you will have a concurrency issue to address; give the database a chance and only fix it if it becomes a real problem. My experience is that COUNT(*) can be surprisingly quick.

I've got a table with 1.2M records (and it has the right indexes); just tried `select count(*) from table_name where field=11;` takes 0.02 seconds and returns 104, to count 500k records takes 0.15 seconds. This is using mysql on a fairly low spec VPS.

The key thing is to do some performance tests and to only optimize away from the easiest most reliable solution when there is a genuine performance issue.

Comment: To add credence to this I've just done a count on a table with over 200M records in using `WHERE IndexedColumn = x` and it took less than a second (SQL Server 2008).

Answer (score 2):

Database normalisation rules say that you shouldn't have any values in your database that you can programatically construct based on other values in your database. So if you're all about "proper engineering", you should count topics every time they need to be shown.

Under normal circumstances, keeping a counter value will not increase performance by much. It should be possible to write your queries in such a way that the performance hit of recalculating those values whenever they need to be displayed would be negligible, if at all noticeable. As indicated in other posts, `COUNT`, even with a condition specified, can be very fast. Remember to use indices where necessary.

In the end, you'll have to decide. Depending on the required usage, having your database normalised may impede performance enough to warrant paying the price, making your application just that little bit less performant, and adding a counter somewhere. However, denormalising your database should always be a last resort.

Comment: Appreciate the comment. Also, good point. I'll try to reword and make it clear that it should be able to construct queries in such a way that the performance issue will, practically, disappear. Denormalisation should be a very last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think these two steps are optional.

```
If you dont update the count whenever someone creates/deletes a thread,
which count will you display on your forum?
```

Whenever there is any update i.e create/delete you have to increment/decrement the counter.
Then while displaying you can always display the count.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM topics WHERE forum_id = :forum_id`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest updating the count as new posts are added or deleted.  This update should be accurate, so it will need to do some locking.  Locking will create some contention on the parent records (threads updating forums, posts updating threads, etc.)  Make sure you have indexes defined so this update is fast.

When users browse the forum, don't lock the records at all.  I wouldn't care about dirty reads, because being 100% accurate is not as critical as in, say, accounting software.  The forums is a living entity, so it is OK if it looks slightly different between page loads.

Also, you might want to run some queries occasionally to verify the counts are correct.